# Connecting to remote mongodb in nodejs fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Trying to connect to MongoDB fails and spits out a very unhelpful error message:

```
trying to connect to Mongo...
trying to set up collection...

/home/mike/dev/bitbucket/mqtt-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:409
      throw err
            ^
[object Object]
```

It hangs at `trying to connect to Mongo...` for a long time, then spits out `trying to set up collection...` as it fails, and never reaches `collection set up` at the end of the `setupCollection()` function.

my app.js:

```
var mqtt=require('mqtt');
var mongodb=require('mongodb');

var mongodbClient=mongodb.MongoClient;
//var mongodbURI='mongodb://user:pass@host:27017/nodejs';
var mongodbURI='mongodb://host:27017/nodejs';
var deviceRoot="owntracks/mike";
var collection,client;

console.log("trying to connect to Mongo...")
mongodbClient.connect(mongodbURI,setupCollection);


function setupCollection(err,db) {
        console.log("trying to set up collection...")
        if(err) throw err;
        collection=db.collection("owntracks");
        client=mqtt.createClient(mqtt_port,'mqtt_host')
        client.subscribe(deviceRoot+"#")
        client.on('message', insertEvent);
        console.log("collection set up")

}

function insertEvent(topic,payload) {
```

As you can see, I've tried with and without the username and password with the same behaviour. I haven't tried with a local Mongo instance yet.

The surrounding function of line 409 in `mongo_client.js` is:

```
399   // Set up the db options
400   var db = new Db(object.dbName, serverConfig, object.db_options);
401   // Open the db
402   db.open(function(err, db){
403     if(err) {
404       return process.nextTick(function() {
405         try {
406           callback(err, null);
407         } catch (err) {
408           if(db) db.close();
409           throw err
410         }
411       });
412     }
```

My questions are:

1. What could be causing the failure? Is it possible to tell from this?
2. I'm new to JS and Node; how can I get more detailed error messages?

Comment: Somewhere, you're catching the error and displaying it badly. Remove that piece of logic and you should get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: I'm not catching the error anywhere! My app.js file is the only code I've written, all the rest comes from the mongodb package in nodejs. I tried surrounding my `mongodbClient()` function with a try/catch but that made no difference. Is there no way to get node to print the call stack?

Comment: The fact that you have an `[object Object]` at the end of your output stream indicates you're trying to `console.log()` an object somewhere, I'm *guessing* it's the error. The default action is not to `console.log` anything, so you undeniably have that *somewhere*.

Comment: Like I said - my app.js is the only code I've written and that didn't have any `console.log()` statements in it. I added some after I got this error and the ones I added only log strings (as you can see above). If there is a `console.log(obj)` somewhere, it would have to be in the node mongodb module, and I can't think how I'd find that.

Comment: Alright, let's go this from the other direction. Setup a breakpoint on `console.log("trying to set up collection...")` and examine `err`.

Comment: I have discovered Node Inspector! I've been doing all this in vim, so I installed that to put a break point on. Down the call stack it's just a plain vanilla socket timeout and I've since tried it with a local mongodb which works absolutely fine. The problem is almost certainly the connection URI, or the remote server where Mongo is installed. Thanks for your help!